# MatchParen and cursorcolumn conflict

Tags: vim

Vim is not showing the matching brackets on the same column when I do in _vimrc

```
:set cursorline
:set cursorcolumn
```

Actually I have in my _vimrc

```
:set cursorline
:set cursorcolumn

:highlight CursorLine  term=underline  guibg=#fffcd0  cterm=underline
:highlight CursorColumn  term=underline  guibg=#e1ffd5  cterm=underline
```

Then the matching bracket on the same column does not highlight.

I tried below playing with guibg and guifg with Black and Cyan and gui=inverse as:

```
:highlight MatchParen  guibg=somecolors  guifg=othercolor  gui=inverse
```

But nothing works.

I need the highlighted current column as #e1ffd5 and current line as #fffcd0, and
the matching brackets highlighted.

I need the both. How can I?

Normally if you do not turn on cursorline and cursorcolumn then there will be no problem, vim will show every matching paren normally, like:
[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69gzX.png).

All the problems will take place if you turn on cursorline and cursorcolumn. The matching paren highlight on the same column at the other end will be vanished, like:
[image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35oSp.png).

Finally I tried

```
:highlight MatchParen    guibg=Black guifg=Cyan gui=inverse
```

But this also is not very perfect. Paren on the other side will fade into white, which I never want.

I want everything perfectly, better saying a mixture of picture 1 and 2 both.
I tried but I could not.

Comment: Just set the foreground color to NONE.

Comment: I tried everything, nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Setting `ctermfg` and/or `guifg` to `NONE` gets you what you want.

```
hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 ctermfg=NONE gui=NONE guibg=#2d2d2d guifg=NONE
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 ctermfg=NONE gui=NONE guibg=#2d2d2d guifg=NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

With the cterm settings I found the following.

First I found that the following command made the matching paren disappear.

```
:hi MatchParen    cterm=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=white
```

While my cursor was on these pren, I switched over to next vertical split, and saw that the colors of the matching peren were reversed.

That led me to the solution with the following command.

```
:hi MatchParen    cterm=reverse
```

or

```
:hi MatchParen    cterm=reverse ctermfg=<your color> ctermbg=<your color>
```

I think the color you are looking for is

```
(steelblue and black) or (black and steelblue)
```

My setting and I didn't change :hi cursorcolumn.

```
:hi MatchParen    cterm=reverse ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```